# Asp.net GridView export to excel issue

Tags: asp.net, .net, ajax

I'm trying to export my `GridView` to excel, but I'm having some problems.

At first I got few other errors so I added `EnableEventValidation ="false"` to my page, and I added `public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)` in my source code.
Now i'm getting this error from javascript:

**`Microsoft JScript runtime error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message received from the server could not be parsed.`**

I'm guessing it's because my grid is in `ajax` update panel, but i'm not sure about it.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: it sounds like you got a server side exception and you also told the script manager to handle the error. make sure you don't have any response.write or response.redirect since they don't work well with update panel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of your update panel if you remove your update panel it will work or you can set a PostBackTrigger for detail see this blog post

http://nice-tutorials.blogspot.com/2009/06/export-gridview-to-excel-within-update.html